# ransack custom attributes sorting in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ransack

I'm trying to sort custom attributes using ransack.

my view looks like:

```
%th= sort_link @open_search, :status_step_name, 'Status Step', { open_page: '' }, :remote => true
```

in my model:

```
scope :status_step_name, lambda {|name| approvals.where("status != 'approved'").order("position").first}
```

This is customized column displayed in the table. This works fine and i'm able to display current status step for projects, however i'm not able to sort using this column name.

is i'm missing something??
Any ideas??